# Python: Overriding a member with a property?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I was trying to override a member of a Python (2.7) class with a property, as shown in the following code:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

class Derived(Base):
    foo = property(lambda self: 2)

print Derived().foo
```

However, the last line prints 1 instead of 2. From the way I thought properties are supposed to work (ie., easily change a member to a function later on), this seems counter-intuitive to me. Am I missing something? Is there some workaround?

Comment: I'm sure this is just for example, but using `property()` as a decorator on an actual `def` would be far more readable than using it directly with a `lambda`.

Comment: Moral of the story: _always_ use new-style classes.

Comment: @Lattyware: Actually, I personally prefer the `lambda` style in properties that simple :)

Comment: @rainer Well, properties that simple shouldn't exist (as I said, I presume this was just for example). Anything complex enough to be worth using a property would be better off done as I explained above, for readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't work because you aren't using a new-style class.  Properties are `descriptors` which only work on new-style classes.  What your code is doing is this:

You create a class `Derived` with a class attribute `foo`.  Then when you create an instance of the class, `Base.__init__` takes over since `Derived` has no `__init__` and you add the instance attribute `foo` which takes precedence to the class attribute.

If you change:

```
class Base: #old style class
```

to:

```
class Base(object):  #new style class
```

You'll run into an entirely new problem, mainly that your property doesn't have an appropriately defined `setter`, so when you do `self.foo = 1` in `Base.__init__` you'll get an `AttributeError`

Comment: And after that problem is fixed, it won't work because it will overwrite the parent's `foo` member directly anyway, so you'll never be able to set `foo`.

Comment: And to use a new-style class...? =) Your class shuold derive from object. class Base(object):

Comment: @sr2222 That's not true - the first argument to [`property()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is the getter. This will produce a perfectly fine read-only property, on a new-style class.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, that's right.  Got the argument order backwards in my head somehow...

Comment: @Lattyware -- but that `self.foo` is set in `Base.__init__` which will attempt to use the property.

Comment: @mgilson True, so it will error out there, but my point was that the property will be created.

Comment: Thanks! I never realized properties are meant exclusively for new-style classes. Strange that, for simple cases, they also work on old-style classes.